# How should I clean stone surfaces prior to applying sealer?

Tags: tile, maintenance, stone, granite

I apply impregnating sealer to all my tile and stone surfaces annually.

I had been cleaning it with just soap and water, then letting the surface dry for a few minutes before applying the sealer. It occurred to me that perhaps introducing water to the stone prior to sealing was a bad idea and that perhaps I should use a more volatile liquid to clean it?

How should I clean my natural stone surfaces before applying an impregnating sealer?

Comment: Just checked my container of Miracle 511 impregnating sealer...no mention of cleaning prior to application whatsoever, oh well. IIRC last time I did as you describe: I cleaned with soap and water and gave it 15 minutes or so. I've been happy with the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [How do I clean my Natural Stone tiles and slabs?](http://www.daltile.com/information/faq/natural-stone-faq)

> Clean stone surfaces with a few drops of neutral PH stone cleaner
>   available at retail stores or at your local tile and stone dealer, or
>   a mild liquid dishwashing detergent and warm water. Use a clean rag
>   mop on floors and a soft cloth for other surfaces for best results.
>   Too much cleaner or soap may leave a film and cause streaks. Do not
>   use products that contain lemon, vinegar or other acids on marble or
>   limestone. Rinse the surface thoroughly after washing with the soap
>   solution and dry with a soft cloth. Change the rinse water frequently.
>   Do not use scouring powders or creams; these products contain
>   abrasives that may scratch the surface.

Comment: How long should I allow to dry before I apply sealer?

Comment: ^^ "dry with a soft cloth" -- Even though you are drying it, I would still give it at least an extra hour.

Comment: and soft-bristle brush (NOT metal) in place of rag for tougher spots.